# React-sortble-tree: how to find the parent node based on the current node: getNodeAtPath-way-of-working?

Tags: reactjs

I have been struggling with this for days now.
The problem is that I can't access the parent node, based on the current node.

Situation:
I have a tree like in this example: https://codesandbox.io/s/old-fog-djhd2

Create a child under the first node.
When that child is created, create a new (grand) child as a child under the first child.
Now you have a tree that goes 3 levels deep.
Click on the "update parent" button of the last child.
Check the console.

The console.log always returns null for the parentnode, when I expected to see the parent node info.

So, what's the correct way to use getNodeAtPath so that it actually returns something?
Or is there a better way to find the parent node of the node that's being deleted/clicked/...?

Thanks SO MUCH in advance!

Answer (score 0):

you are calling **getNodeAtPath** incorrectly. The parameter has to be an object like this:

```
getNodeAtPath(
      {
        treeData: this.state.treeData,
        path: newPath,
        getNodeKey
      }
    );
```

Comment: Omg...so obvious. Gonna try it later! Thanks!!